# php-fpm won't load www.conf

Tags: php, unix

I'm trying to set php7.3-fpm to use socket by providing a www.conf file. But php-fpm seems to ignore it completely. The php-fpm.conf file is the default one (location: /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf) which has this line at the end:

```
include=etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf
```

This means that it will try to include any conf file in path: `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/` path, right? So I created my www.conf file there with content:

```
[www]
listen = /var/run/php-fpm.sock
```

After restarting php-fpm and using `php-fpm -tt` I see it's still using the defaults.

```
....
[23-Dec-2020 11:12:02] NOTICE: [www]
[23-Dec-2020 11:12:02] NOTICE:  listen = 9000
...
```

I tried putting my config in multiple paths with same result:

- `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`
- `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`
- `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf`
- `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

Comment: What do the log files show?

Comment: It is likely you were editing wrong config file. Try to use `strace` to trace the syscalls. You will find `open` syscall to the correct config file. Use this command: `strace -iv php-fpm 2>&1 | grep open`, then look at the output, what are files being opened by php-fpm?.

Comment: It shows nothing, and if I run the command without a pipe it says: `bash: strace: command not found`. I think it's because I'm running in a Docker image based on php7.3-fpm which has a lot of functionalities removed for size reasons. Minor development: I manage to make it work by placing the www.conf contents into the php-fpm.conf file directly. Functional but ugly... wish I knew the included path.

Comment: One hint is exactly there in the php-fpm.conf file: `Relative path can also be used. They will be prefixed by: the global prefix if it's been set (-p argument), /usr/local otherwise`. I think i'm in the otherwise situation. But cannot really know for sure.

Comment: Another update: if I include my `www.conf` file path directly into the `php-fpm.conf` file it doesn't work (i get bad gateway) but if I copy-paste the contents into `php-fpm.conf` it works.